# Is there going to be a VimConf this year?

Tags: events

Since Covid-19 hit, many conferences have been canceled or moved online.

Are we going to have a conference for Vim and NeoVim in 2020?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [official VimConf](https://vimconf.org/) has been [canceled](https://vimconf.org/2020/) in 2020:

> We have decided to cancel VimConf 2020 due to the changes in the social situation caused by COVID-19 (SARS-CoV-2, a new type of coronavirus). We also believe that one of the following conditions must be met in order to restart VimConf.
>
> - COVID-19 dissipates or is rendered harmless
> - Vaccines are developed and fully distributed, making it easier to vaccinate
> - The more specific drugs are developed, the lower the rate of severity or the lower the number of reproductions
> - The socially accepted notion of “adequate preventive measures” is formed
>
> We apologize for not being able to meet your expectations of VimConf 2020, and ask for your understanding and cooperation.

However, there's a separate online VimConf conference happening at [vimconf.live](https://www.vimconf.live/), using the [hopin.to](https://hopin.to/) platform.

The conference is happening September 5th & 6th, 2020 and registration is free.

Disclaimer: I have no association with the conference, with the conference organizers, with any of the sponsors, or with the platform hosting it. I just thought it was of general interest for the Vim community, and so on topic for this stack, particularly since it's free and online, so it's easy for anyone who would like to watch the talks.